# Should I change my HTML Contact Form to PHP in order for it to work or do I need to fix the Server?

Tags: php, html, mamp, contact-form

Hello Guys Im brand spanking new to PHP. I created a contact form in html. I barely installed Mamp on my mac last night and directed the web server to my projects folder in my home folder (not where my project is located).

right now I created two files, one file is the html file for the contact form and the other file is the webform.php.

What do I need to do in order to make this work? Should I change the html file to php or do I need to redirect my web server?

When I click on the send button im getting an error in my browser saying "This page isn’t workingIf the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405"

```
<div class="contact-form bg-yellow p-2">
            <h2 class="m-heading">Contact us</h2>
            <p>Pleaes use the form below to contact us</p>
            <form action="webform.php" method="POST" class="contactform">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" Email="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                    <textarea name="message" rows="10" id="message" placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-black">
            </form>
        </div>
```

[image: (not sure why but i cant paste php code in here so here is a screenshot.]

Comment: Comment out the mail() line (line 9) using //. Do you still get the error?

Comment: still not working. WHen I try the contact form in my browser I get this error. "If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405"

Do I need to connect the mamp server to this project?

Comment: Are these files in your htdocs folder in MAMP and you are accessing it through http://localhost/index.html

Comment: after I created the code files all I did was right click on the html form and selected "open with live server".

Comment: Do I need to move my entire folder to htdocs folder in mamp? I have about 20 html files.

Comment: Yes. To run files on your MAMP server they need to be in your htdocs folder

Comment: instead of moving all of my files is there a way i can connect MAMP to my project?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50590/mamp-html-source-folder

Comment: Thank you so much for your help I really appreciate it.